# RAID1 array auto removed a totally physically damaged member disk. Should the disk replacement procedure be any different than standard `mdadm --add`?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1

**RAID Setup**

One RAID 1 array with 2 members:

- sda1
- sdb1

Due to hardware failure, `sda` is not visible in `/dev/` anymore and the array also does include it anymore (RAID 1 status: S)

**Playbook to replace array member**

`sda1` must be replaced. The typical playbook to replace a RAID 1 array member is the following:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1
mdadm /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sda1
```

**Problem**

With the disk effectively gone, none of these commands (especially the later one) can be issued.

It looks like the RAID array already considered the disk removed from the array.

1. What are the consequences of physically removing a RAID 1 disk member without issuing `mdadm --remove /dev/sdaX` first  ?
2. Should the array member replacement procedure be any different than the one below ?

```
Insert new physical disk
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sda1
```

Comment: If the disk is already dead and gone, there's no need to explicitly fail and remove it. Just replace, with or without power depends on hotplug support on the port.